# search sharepoint with ldap query

Tags: sharepoint, ldap

I think the answer is no, but I haven't been satisfied with my marathon google searches today.

I have several stand alone devices (MFP, phone system, etc) that can search an LDAP directory for contact information such as fax or telephone numbers.  I have all of this information organized in SharePoint and I'd like to be able to search this list from those devices.  The trouble is that SharePoint isn't an LDAP server so I can't configure the devices to search it directly using LDAP (they're old enough to not support SharePoint via WebDAV so that's not an option either).

What I'm wondering is if there's any software that I can install on a windows server that acts as an LDAP server with sharepoint as the back-end?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a sharepoint expert. If you sharepoint data is not stored in an LDAP compatible store (Windows Active Directory is one of them), it's not going to get accessed using LDAP.

I doubt such software exists but you can always code it ;)